# How can you store the results from a forEach in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

`DataSet#foreach(f)` applies the function `f` to each row in the dataset. In a clustered environment, the data is split across the cluster. How can the results from each of these functions be collected?

For example, say the function would count the number of characters stored in each row. How can you create a DataSet or RDD that contains the results of each of these functions applied to each row?

Comment: use `map` instead of `foreach`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition for `foreach` looks something like :

> ```
> final  def  foreach(f: (A) ⇒ Unit): Unit
> ```
>
> `f` : The function that is applied for its side-effect to every element.
>                The result of function `f` is discarded

`foreach` in Scala is generally used to denote the usage of a function that involves a side-effect, e.g. printing to STDOUT.

If you want to return something by applying a particular function, you'll have to use `map`

> ```
> final  def  map[B](f: (A) ⇒ B): List[B]
> ```

I copied the syntax from the documentation for `List` but it'll be something similar for RDDs as well.

As you can see, it works the function `f` on datatype `A` and returns a collection of datatype `B` where `A` and `B` can be the same data type as well.

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Array(
      "String1",
      "String2",
      "String3" ))

scala> rdd.foreach(x => (x, x.length) ) 

// Nothing happens

rdd.map(x => (x, x.length) ).collect

// Array[(String, Int)] = Array((String1,7), (String2,7), (String3,7))
```